# Looping through post count php

Tags: php, html, sql

```
echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";
$counter=0;
if( $row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
mysql_data_seek($result,0);

while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$counter++;
echo "<tr>
    <td>".$row['name']."</td>
    <td> "?><input type="hidden" id="id" name="id[]" value=" <?php echo $row['id']?>"> <input id="txt_port" name="txt_port[]" type="text" class="required" title="Port. This is a required field" value=" <?php echo $row['Destination_port'] ?> "></td> 
    <?php
    echo "<td><a onclick='return show_confirm();'><input name='update[]' class='button' type='submit' value='Update'></input></a></td></tr>";

    if(ISSET($_POST["update"]) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){   
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $port=$_POST['txt_port'];
    $menu=$_GET['Menu'];

    echo $id[$counter];
    echo $port[$counter];

    $result=mysql_query("UPDATE protocols SET Destination_port=".$port[$counter]." WHERE id=".$id[$counter].";");

   // header("Location: Overview.php?Menu=".$menu."&Overview=1");
    }
    }
echo "</form>";
```

I made a simple table which as got 3 columns, the first column is a name, second one has a textbox which contains a number (with a hidden id that I need) and last one is a button to update that specific row.

The big problem is when I echo $id[$counter] and echo $port[counter] this stupid counter never counts up. I always end up with the same data! In total it loops 4 times but it gives me the data of the first record.

Any ideas please help.

Comment: *"this **stupid** counter never counts"* - It's not the counter's fault. *"Like a craftsman blaming it on his tools."*

Comment: it gives you the data of the first record each time, or never gives you the data of the first record?

Comment: the data of the first record each time

Comment: `echo count($id);`: are there really 4 items in the array?

Comment: Unless `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['txt_port']` are arrays, you're trying to access strings as arrays - which will work because strings are an array of characters, but not the way you want. See `id = $_POST['id']` and `$port = $_POST['txt_port']` along with `$id[$counter]` and `$port[$counter]`.

Comment: What type of data is in your `$_POST['id']`, because you are treating it like it is an array (by assigning it to `$id` and then trying to read `$id[$counter]`).

Comment: In $_POST['id'] is normally the value '1' or '2'. Depends on the row

Comment: have you tried a for loop instead of a while loop? use sizeof() to get the array size and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please show your whole code? I see you have $result variable but I didnt see when you built the sql. In additional, it is highly recommend that you use mysqli or PDO as mysql_ are deprecating.